# Create and manage database in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently learning the basics of ASP.NET and visual studio 2013. My teacher has given me an assignment to create a basic student registration form and when the student clicks submit, his data should be uploaded to the database.

And also there should be an option to display all the submitted data in a single table in a webpage.

I've created the basic web form but I don't know how to create and connect to a database.

Using PHP, I could create a mysql connection and use sql queries for the rest.

How do I do it in asp.net and sql server?

PS. I'm using sql server 2012 and visual studio 2013 community edition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely your teacher has covered the items that you need to use in your assignment.....

Comment: Just create an MVC project and the created project has everything in it using EF.

Comment: actually, I'm doing it using Web Forms

Comment: @QualityCatalyst - and by doing so the student will learn absolutely nothing.

Comment: Look for a program called Sql Server Management Studio, which should already be installed on your computer.

Comment: @OsamaArshad - have you tried google or your favorite search engine?  Query ADO.NET and see what comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options here. I would recommend based on what appears to be limited experience a tool like Entity Framework https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx or NHibernate http://nhibernate.info/ would be sufficient. The benefit of these tools is they can actually generate your entire database from your model or vs versa. Nhibernate might be a little more complex for you to setup so I would go with Entity Framework. Google for some samples, there should be plenty!

If you are familiar with PHP a similar such tool would be Doctrine http://www.doctrine-project.org/ which I have used and it is pretty good.

The key really is you need to adjust to a totally new paradigm for development (Unless you have already used OO development within PHP)

Good luck with you development.